# Disable fragment back stack animations - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation, back-stack

How are you able to disable all fragment animations including the exit animation when clearing the back stack, currently I am using the following code but it doesn't seem to stop the animation exiting the screen, rather it only stops the animation of the new fragment entering the screen.

The code that I'm using is as follows:

**Menu Fragment - code used to clear back stack**

```
    private void clearBackStack() {
        FragmentUtils.sDisableFragmentAnimations = true;
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        FragmentUtils.sDisableFragmentAnimations = false;
    }
```

**Fragment Utils Class:**

```
public class FragmentUtils {
    public static boolean sDisableFragmentAnimations = false;
}
```

**All fragments have this:**

```
@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    if (FragmentUtils.sDisableFragmentAnimations) {
        Animation a = new Animation() {};
        a.setDuration(0);
        return a;
    }
    return super.onCreateAnimation(transit, enter, nextAnim);
}
```

**Navigation menu code (where I want to disable the animations)**

```
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_events:

                    replaceFragment(new MainFragment());

                    break;
                case R.id.action_promotions:

                    replaceFragment(new MainFragment());
                    break;

                case R.id.action_menu:

                    clearBackStack();
                    replaceFragment(new MenuFragment());
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void replaceFragment(BaseFragment fragment, int resId, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(0, 0);
    transaction.replace(resId, fragment);
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input with that code,

The issue with this is that I want to remove the animation of the Fragment held in the back stack not the animation of the navigation menu.

For instance, in other parts of my code I am calling the method, transaction.addToBackStack(null) and what is going wrong is when the user hits a navigation button it tries to pop these off the stack and the animation still plays.